# Access "self" in add-on from separate module file

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

My .py file got big enough that it was time to split it into multiple files. Originally, it would have some bpy.props, then later functions could access that with

```
    lanes = bpy.props.IntProperty( 
    name = "Lanes",
    default = 2,
    description = "Number of lanes"
    )

def execute (self, context):
    def someFunction():
        print(self.lanes)
```

someFunction is now so big enough I split it into a separate file, imported with importlib.reload. **init**.py runs and can import that function and run it, but messes up when trying to refer to self again:

```
curveSetup() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

The script previously found self because it was one giant file. how do I access self again now they're in different files?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with with python in blender, but it sounds like you're having a scope problem. When working with python, you'll want to split up classes and functions into separate files pretty commonly - since Blender's Python is no different, you should have no problem doing the same.

In your example however, you provide very little detail. How are your files structured? What do they look like? "self" is usually a variable accessed from within a class instance. Your snippet doesn't include a Class definition.

Answer (score 1):

A buddy helped out with this. In the secondary file, I added an optional argument def `someFunction(lanes)` and use `print(lanes)` instead of `print(self.lanes)`. Then in **init**.py, when I call the function I use `someFunction(self.lanes)`